# Saving the selected item from a NSPopupbutton with NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I've tried numerous things and cannot get it to function...

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[my_popup_button selectedItem] forKey:@"selected"];
```

Does not work, got any suggestions?

Comment: Is this the only code your using to save the data to NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from a minimal example I just created:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *popupButton;
- (IBAction)onPopupBtnSelectedItemChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.popupButton selectItemAtIndex:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"selectedItemIndex"]];
}


- (IBAction)onPopupBtnSelectedItemChanged:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.popupButton.indexOfSelectedItem                            
                                               forKey:@"selectedItemIndex"];
}
```

Just tried it and it works like a charm.
Best,

Flo

Comment: It is not working at the moment it is suggesting that the dot in _self.popupbutton_ should be changed to -> which isnt working...

Comment: I think you should definitely read a book on Objective-C before getting serious! I will add more info to the post.

Comment: I still seem to be having a problem, are there any boxes to be unchecked on the popupbutton in the inspector perhaps?

Comment: Let me see if I still have the demo project. I can send you that so you can see by yourself what's going on.

Comment: There you go. Let me know when you downloaded the project! https://www.dropbox.com/s/tak7czd7tv1s39l/Popup%20Button.zip

Comment: I downloaded it onto a flash drive from my PS3, I'll test it tomorrow, thanks very much!